# moving laravel public folder gives ' looks like something went wrong '

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, server, webserver

it worked fine when the file structure was:

```
/bin
....
....
/public_ftp
/public_html/app
/public_html/bootstrap
...
/public_html/public
....
....
/www
```

but when i changed it to:

```
/bin
/laravel/app
/laravel/bootstrap
....
....
/public_ftp
...
/public_html/css
/public_html/js
/public_html/index.php
....
....
/www
```

and i also changed index.php to:

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

but when i opened index.php it shows

**Whoops, looks like something went wrong.**

laravel log

```
production.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.' in /home/fabitzza/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php:43
```

*this error was not there before when every this was in `public_html`*

Comment: Check your current PHP version and required PHP version for current Laravel.

Comment: php version is 5.6

Comment: And whare is your laravel version ?

Comment: "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"

Comment: You must required 5.6.4 or above php  version for laravel 5.3

Comment: AES-256-CBC requires 32 character long key(on .env). But "SomeRandomString" only have 16  characters. So run `php artisan key::generate` command to get a 32 characters long key

Comment: actually its not the version problem because it worked before when every this was in public_html director problem occurs when i moved it to different directory. I have mentioned in my question above

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  There are no commands defined in the "key:" namespace.          
  Did you mean this?                                              
      key

Comment: Suggestions for your future error: Try to copy and paste part of your error log to Google rather than asking SO straightaway. I know that you're a beginner, so this is the best way to learn : Google, after hours of searching, if still stuck, use SO. It's most likely every errors that you have and you will have, somebody already asked out there. It will be better to research first, so you won't be judged by SO people and your future employer as a lazy developer :)

Comment: ok i will keep that in mind.

Comment: @codenut great! Welcome to SO, I'm upvoting so this question will be in the neutral score again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command

```
php artisan key:generate
```

and the clear config cache using

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  There are no commands defined in the "key:" namespace.          
  Did you mean this?                                              
      key

Comment: Try to run these command from project directory

Comment: i think this is the php artisan key:generate . single :  not double ::

Comment: Yup, you're correct, thats my bad, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: it worked and now i am getting log detail on my page same as like https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9080 but before it was just **Whoops, looks like something went wrong.**

Comment: just one more update its not `php artisan config:cache` its `php artisan config:clear` from https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9080#issuecomment-222083043. and thank you. @Saumya Rastogi

Comment: Glad to see that it helped, Thanks :)